# Node.js switch/case not breaking when condition is met

Tags: node.js, switch-statement

Seeing strange behavior with a switch/case statement in node.js. For some reason the switch statement will not break when the condition is satisfied, executing on the final case listed regardless of which case is initially satisfied. Previously it was working, and now it just stopped functioning as expected. I think there is likely some minor syntax error in my code, but I cannot identify. Code below:

```
router.get('/element/chart', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res) => {
    const path = require('path')
    const {spawn} = require('child_process')
    console.log(current_data_page_id)
    console.log(typeof current_data_page_id)
    
    switch(current_data_page_id) {
        case "100":
            function runScript(){
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_file1.py')]);
            } 
            console.log("MADE IT HERE");
            break;
        case "101":
            function runScript(){
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_file2.py')]);
            }
            break;
        case "200":
            function runScript(){
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_file3.py')]);
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Data page ID does not match current options") 
    }
    const subprocess = runScript()
    // print output of script
    subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        var dataToSend = data.toString();
        console.log(dataToSend);
        res.send(dataToSend)
        res.end('end')
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`error:${data}`);
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
        console.log("Closed");
    });

});
```

Below is the console output. The dataToSend variable prints as expected (I did not include b/c it is extremely long); however the value, as mentioned, is representative of the third and final case ("200").

```
100
string
MADE IT HERE
```

Comment: All `function` declarations are hoisted to the top of the containing scope.  So, only the last one is ever in effect.  instead, you need a function assignment.  `myFn = function() {...}` in each `case` and then you can call `myFn()` later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a JavaScript scoping issue: by defining in a switch/case statement you are overriding the `runScript()` function (in this specific case) three times before you would invoke it finally with `subprocess`, so it will always execute the `case "200"` (because of the `subprocess`).

You are able to solve the issue by using **[arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**.

Here is a simplified example for your use case:

```js
const current_data_page_id = "101";
let runScript;

switch(current_data_page_id) {
        case "100":
            runScript = () => { console.log(100) };
            console.log("MADE IT HERE 100");
            break;
        case "101":
            runScript = () =>  { console.log(101) };
            console.log("MADE IT HERE 101");
            break;
        case "200":
            runScript = () => { console.log(200) };
            console.log("MADE IT HERE 200");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Data page ID does not match current options");
    }
const subprocess = runScript();
```